# Are all of the roots of $P(x) = \prod_{k=0}^n (x+a_k) +2\prod_{k=0}^n (x+b_k)$ real?

Tags: polynomials, roots

> For $a_0 <b_0 <a_1 <b_1 <... <a_n <b_n$, prove whether or not all the roots of the polynomial 
>   $$P(x)= \prod_{k=0}^n {(x+a_k)} +2\prod_{k=0}^n {(x+b_k)} , x\in\Bbb R,$$ 
>   are real.

Usually when a normal polynomial is being given, we use IVP to check wheather or not there exit roots of the polynomial.  But here I can't understand how I've to proceed.

Comment: I still think there should be some parentheses somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof that $P(x)$ has at least one real root; I suspect the approach can be extended to all the roots, but I'll leave it to the reader.

First, observe that $P(-a_0)=2\prod_{k=0}^n (b_k-a_0)>0$ since $a_0$ is less than all the $b_k$.  Then $P(-b_0)=2\prod_{k=0}^n (a_k-b_0)$. Since $a_0>b_0$ and $a_k>b_0$ for all $k>1$, we know that $P(-b_0)<0$. So $P(x)$ changes sign between $-a_0$ and $-b_0$, and since $P(x)$ is a continuous function (it's a polynomial) we conclude that there's a real root in the interval $(-a_0,-b_0)$.

Comment: Yes. All the roots are real in such a way